# NGINX: proxy_cache altering headers

Tags: nginx, amazon-web-services, proxy, cache, amazon-s3

I have been having trouble building a proxy between my server and s3 to cache requests. I finally boiled it down to a single point of failure...

```
http{
  proxy_cache_path /home/cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=S3_CACHE:10m inactive=24h max_size=500m;
  ...

    location / {
      proxy_cache                     S3_CACHE;
      proxy_pass                      http://MY_BUCKET.s3.amazonaws.com/;
      proxy_pass_request_headers      on;
    }
  }
}
```

if I remove `proxy_cache S3_CACHE;` the headers are sent and accepted by s3 allowing a get request for the images which then responds with the images. If I leave it in, the headers are sent and then rejected returning a 403 error.

This leads me to believe that enabling the cache is altering the headers in some unforeseen way that is causing them to be rejected by S3.

I am hoping someone here may have some insight into why this is happening...

And also... how I can capture the headers that nginx is sending to s3 so that I can compare them to the original, pre-proxy headers.

Comment: you can capture the traffic sent to s3 with tcpdump and view it in wireshark.

Comment: @EugeneM.Zheganin do you have an example of how this would be done?

Comment: it's actually pretty easy - run `tcpdump -s 0 -w http.pcap -ni <your server interface name> port 80`, wait for the exchange to take place (or initiate one) and press Ctrl-C. this (supposing you communicate with outer world and s3 on port 80, because viewing HTTPS sessions is useless) will give you the http.pcap capture file. you then download it via scp on your computer, download and install wireshark and load the capture file into it. then examine it for headers - the ones received and transmitted between your server and clients and between your server and S3.

Comment: Perhaps an easier way: install the Firebug in Firefox, and examine the headers received/sent with and without proxy_cache. Also examine such headers when communicating directly with S3 bucket without your server in path.

Comment: I've got it open in wireshark right now. Thanks! This might be what I'm looking for

Comment: So it goes like this (chronologically)...with cache disabled: Client makes HEAD request --> proxy --> S3 THEN Client makes GET request --> proxy --> S3 THEN S3 sends image --> proxy --> client. with cache enabled: Client makes HEAD request --> proxy transforms this into a GET --> S3 THEN proxy sends 403 --> client AND THEN S3 sends 403 --> proxy. WTF? So the rejection that the client receives isn't even coming from S3 it is coming directly from the proxy, and then S3 rejects the proxy.

Comment: you mean, 403 is issued by your nginx when cache is enabled, and not by S3 ? You can actually loot in it, enabling extended log format, like this: `log_format nginx_extended '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
                    '$host "$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
                    '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" $request_time '
                    '$upstream_addr $upstream_status $upstream_cache_status';` - this will give you backend status and cache status.